# TLSv1.1 Server Hello Delay

Tags: java, tomcat, wso2, wso2-api-manager, tls1.1

Here I'm using WSO2 Api manager 1.7.0 as server(172.x.x.6) and another VM (172.x.x.21) as client.
Server is enabled TCP 8243 port for secured connections.When I tried curl request from my client VM (with certificate), I am experiencing some delays intermittently.(eg: 5 seconds delay for one request out of 20 requests)
In TCPDUMP, I noticed that server has taken around 5 seconds to send "**Server Hello**".
How we can find out the exact reason for this delay? 
Is it from OS level or JVM level or Tomcat level?
Do we have any system parameters to fine tune to eliminate this intermittent delay?

[image: tcpdump]

Comment: Could be a DNS issue. Note that this is a session resumption, not a full handshake.

Comment: No. I'm hitting direct ip. https://172.x.x.6:8243/xxx/xxx/xxxx. As i checked, This has used same session id. how can we identify session resumption?

Comment: Hello @Hasitha, did you found a solution for this problem. I'm observing a similar behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue: around 5sec delay before ServerHello with Java. I figured out that Java on Windows was making a reverse dns lookup for each incoming connection. The DNS based reverse lookup failed, so it also tried a netbios based lookup which caused the delay. You can verify it by looking at a wireshark capture on the server side. Netbios should show up as protocol NBNS (netbios name service) around the ClientHello. The fix for me was to open the network adapter's IPv4 settings and there was a radio button to disable netbios (advanced->wins tab).